# TramineR legend position and axis

Tags: dataframe, plot, traminer

I'm working with TraMineR and I don't know how to arrange my plot. So basically what i would like to have the legend under the plot and to remove the space between the x and y axis. Any help is welcomed.

The plot:

[image]

Sample code:

```
seqdplot(Activities.seq, with.legend=FALSE)

legend("bottom", legend=attr(Activities.seq, "labels"), 
       fill=attr(Activities.seq, "cpal"), 
       inset=-.1, bty="o", xpd=NA, cex=.75,ncol=3)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The family of `seqplot` functions offers a series of arguments to control the legend as well as the axes. Look at the help page of `seqplot` (and of `plot.stslist.statd` for specific `seqdplot` parameters).

For instance, you can suppress the x-axis with `axes=FALSE`, and the y-axis with `yaxis=FALSE`.

To print the legend you can let `seqdplot` display it automatically using the default `with.legend=TRUE` option and control it with for examples `cex.legend` for the font size, `ltext` for the text. You can also use the `ncol` argument to set the number of columns in the legend.

The `seqplot` functions use by default `layout` to organize the graphic area between the plots and the legend. If you need more fine tuning (e.g. to change the default `par(mar=c(5.1,4.1,4.1,2.1))` margins around the plot and the legend), you should create separately the plot(s) and the legend and then organize them yourself using e.g. `layout` or `par(mfrow=...)`. In that case, the separate graphics should be created by setting `with.legend=FALSE`, which prevents the display of the legend and disables the automatic use of `layout`.

The color legend is easiest obtained with `seqlegend`.

I illustrate with the `mvad` data that ships with `TraMineR`. First the default plot with the legend. Note the use of `border=NA` to suppress the too many vertical black lines.

```
library(TraMineR)
data(mvad)
mvad.scode <- c("EM", "FE", "HE", "JL", "SC", "TR")
mvad.seq <- seqdef(mvad, 17:86, 
                   states = mvad.scode,
                   xtstep = 6)

# Default plot with the legend, 
seqdplot(mvad.seq, border=NA)
```

[image]

Now, we suppress the x and y axes and modify the display of the legend

```
seqdplot(mvad.seq, border=NA,
         axes=FALSE, yaxis=FALSE, ylab="",
         cex.legend=1.3, ncol=6, legend.prop=.11)
```

[image]

Here is how you can control the space between the plot and the x and y axes

```
seqdplot(mvad.seq, border=NA, yaxis=FALSE, xaxis=FALSE, with.legend=FALSE)
axis(2, line=-1)
axis(1, line=0)
```

Creating the legend separately and reducing the left, top, and right margins around the legend

```
op <- par(mar=c(5.1,0.1,0.1,0.1))
seqlegend(mvad.seq, ncol=2, cex=2)
par(op)
```

[image]